# Where in this method are numbers checked for primality?

Tags: ruby, primes

Here is a method I found to find the highest prime factor of a number.
Yet there is dark mystery within - including something I once read was forbidden - changing the condition of a loop within the loop.

```
def factorize(orig) # 600851475143
  factors = Hash.new(0)
  n = orig
  i = 2
  sqi = 4
  while sqi <= n do
    if n % i == 0
      n /= i
      factors[i] = true
      puts "Found factor #{i}"
    end
    i += 1
    sqi = i**2
    puts "sqi is #{sqi}"
  end

  if (n != 1) && (n != orig)
    factors[n] = true
  end
  p factors
end

puts factorize(600851475143).keys.max
```

So I see (sort of) how the factors are found.
But where in these lines is the factor checked to make sure it it is prime?

What mathematical insight am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand what's wrong with "changing the condition of a loop within the loop"? That is the only way you can get it to terminate, surely?

Comment: am in a conference - thanks for answers so far! back in an hour

Comment: it isn't wrong - it's obviously the right way - I have just never seen both numbers in a while condition be changeable at the same time. And something I read or watched said to make sure that one side of the equation remained fixed. Such advanced stuff!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method is slightly wrong (just slightly). It should look like this:

```
def factorize(orig)
  factors = Hash.new(0)
  n, i, sqi = orig, 2, 4
  while sqi <= n do
    if n % i == 0
      n /= i
      factors[i] = true
      puts "Found factor #{i}"
    else
      sqi += 2 * i + 1
      i   += 1
    end

    puts "sqi is #{sqi}"
  end

  if (n != 1) && (n != orig)
    factors[n] = true
  end

  p factors
end
```

The difference here is that now, I only increase `i` (and `sqi`) when `i` is *not* a factor of `n`. This is because, like the example of `16` that was highlighted earlier, a number can have multiple instances of any one prime factor, so we should keep checking a number until it is no longer a factor.

**Now** this method *does* guarantee primality, because it always finds the smallest factor of the number (conversely, it only increases the factor it's checking, if it's no longer a factor, which is saying the same thing). And of course the smallest factor of a number must be prime:

**Proof By Contradiction** The smallest factor of a number is prime.

- Suppose the smallest factor, `f` of a number `N` is *not* prime.
- Then `f` has itself, has factors `x` and `y` where `1 < x, y < f` holds true.
- As a result, `x` and `y` must also be factors of `N` **and**, `x`, `y` are both less than `f`!
- This is a contradiction, because we said `f` was the smallest factor of `N`.
- So our original assumption about `f` is false, and `f` must be prime.

I got to this result by inspecting the **invariant** of the loop, which I will add to this answer in due course.

### **EDIT:** Notes on Invariants

An invariant of a loop, is a predicate condition that remains true, before, during and after the running of the loop, and we can use it to prove that a loop is providing us with the answer we want.

In the case of our loop, there is a simple invariant we must keep track of, which is `sqi = i**2` which simply states that `sqi` must always hold the value of the square of `i`. This invariant exists to save us recalculating the square every time to compare it with n. (Which by the way, is why I've changed it to incrementing by `2 * i + 1` in my method, otherwise you might as well put `i*i` in the condition of the loop).

The other part of the invariant is that the `factors` hash (which mathematically I will treat as a set of numbers) is the set of factors of the number `k` such that `n * k = orig`.

The final, and most important part of the invariant is that `i <= f` where `f` is the smallest factor of `n`. (This means that `n % i = 0` only when `i = f`, which means that the loop always finds the smallest factor of `n`, which is a prime factor of `n`).

Writing the invariant is only half the battle, we also need to prove that our method always follows it:

- The first part of the invariant is simple, because we see whenever we update `i` we update `sqi` correctly, and they begin as `2` and `4` respectively.
- The second part, similarly is pretty simple, because we only add `i` as a factor when
  `n % i == 0` is true, and at the same time, we divide `n` by `i`, so as to ensure that the factor added to `k` is removed from `n`.
- Now let's look at the part of the invariant that's crucial to ensuring the list only contains prime factors. Well, to begin with `i = 2` which is the smallest factor of any
  number (not including `1` due to its awkwardness when it comes to primality). Then we need to be certain that we increment `i` as *late* as possible. I.e. when we are sure that it can no longer be a factor.

  Our code only increments `i` when it is not a factor of `n`. If the invariant held before, this means that `i <= f` and `i` is not a factor, therefore **`i < f`**. So the correct behaviour is to increment to get `i` closer to `f`.

  This logic is enough to suggest that when `i` is not a factor, we should increment it, but **not** enough to suggest we shouldn't always increment `i`, for which we need this next piece of logic: If `i` **is** a factor of `n`, it means **`i = f`**, however, it doesn't tell us anything about whether the *next* smallest factor is strictly greater than `f` (as we've seen with `16`, the next smallest factor could be equal to the previous). So this means we shouldn't increment `i` if it is a factor, because doing so may make us miss the next smallest factor.

I hope this bit convinces you about the correctness of the program. It is also possible to write `factorize` with a nested while loop, which I feel might be a little bit simpler to reason about, but they both work basically identically.

Answer (score 1):

`if n % i == 0` checks if n is divisible by `i`. If it is then it sets `factors[i] = true`, if a number has no factors (apart from itself and one); then it is prime.

Answer (score 0):

The factor is *not* checked to make sure it's prime. That's why it breaks (giving non-prime factor) for orig==32:

```
Found factor 2
sqi is 9
sqi is 16
Found factor 4
sqi is 25
{2=>true, 4=>true}
4
```

It could be fixed (while retaining the same logic, i.e. without major rewrites) by replacing `if n % i == 0` with `while n % i == 0 do` (that is, divide n by i while it's possible): then by the time we reach a composite i, all its prime factors would be already "factored out" during prior iterations.